# how to replace answer of first equation with new equation value in JQuery?

Tags: jquery, html, calculator

I am trying to say how can I replace the total value of the first equation with the new equation value in jquery. for example 2 + 2 = 4 first equation answer is 4 i want to replace with new equation.for example 3 + 8 = 11 ?

```
 <input type="text" class="input">
    <button class="oprator" id="butn4">4</button>
    <button class="oprator" id="butn6">6</button>
    <button id="butnplus">+</button>
    <button id="equal">=</button>

$(document).ready(function () {
             $("#butn4").click(function () {
            $(".input").val($(".input").val() + $("#butn4").text())
        });
        $("#butn6").click(function () {
            $(".input").val($(".input").val() + $("#butn6").text())
        });

        $("#butnplus").click(function () {
            $(".input").val($(".input").val() + $("#butnplus").text())
        });
        $("#equal").click(function () {
            $(".input").val((eval($(".input").val())))
        });
    });
```

Comment: `i want to replace with new equation` so When?

Answer (score 1):

## [Never use eval()!](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval#Never_use_eval!)

> how can I replace the total value of the first equation with the new
> equation

What I get is, renew the result each time you use `equal` button, after you get first result, you can sum new values, not sum with old result:

```js
let input = $(".input");

$('.oprator').click(function() {
  var value = $(this).text();
  if (input.hasClass('ready')) {
    input.removeClass('ready')
    input.val('')
  }
  input.val(input.val() + value);
});

$("#butnplus").click(function() {
  input.val(input.val() + '+')
});

$("#equal").click(function() {
  input.addClass('ready')
  input.val((eval(input.val())))
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" class="input">
<button class="oprator" id="butn4">4</button>
<button class="oprator" id="butn6">6</button>
<button id="butnplus">+</button>
<button id="equal">=</button>

<input id="result" type="hidden" />
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you want do this?

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".oprator").click(function() {
    $(".input").val($(".input").val() + $(this).text())
  });
  
  $("#butnplus").click(function() {
    $(".input").val($(".input").val() + $("#butnplus").text())
  });
  
  $("#equal").click(function() {
    $(".input").val((eval($(".input").val())))
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <input type="text" class="input">
 <button class="oprator">1</button>
 <button class="oprator">2</button>
 <button class="oprator">3</button>
 <button class="oprator">4</button>
 <button class="oprator">5</button>
 <button class="oprator">6</button>
 <button class="oprator">7</button>
 <button class="oprator">8</button>
 <button class="oprator">9</button>
 <button class="oprator">0</button>
 <button id="butnplus">+</button>
 <button id="equal">=</button>
```

Comment: Can you please add one more functionality in this calculator that is when I passed a new value for new calculations it does not replace the previous answer.